# Border Background DataTrigger not changing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Want to change properties of the border based on an enum value:

Things like Visibility and opacity seem to change, but not backgrounds or borderbushes...

```
<Border Background="{StaticResource Gradient3}" 
        BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1"  
        Height="25" Width="25" CornerRadius="25">            
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Operation}" Value="0"> <!-- Idle -->
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Operation}" Value="1"> <!-- Failure -->
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"></Setter>                            
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Operation}" Value="2"> <!-- Success-->
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Purple"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple"></Setter>                            
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Operation}" Value="3"> <!-- Running -->
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Purple"></Setter>
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Name="abc">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation                                       
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                    From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1" 
                                    RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="abc"/>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <TextBlock FontWeight="ExtraBold" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">?</TextBlock>
</Border>
```

This code triggers it:

```
private void ExecuteTestConnectionCommand(ConnectionString connection)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
         o =>
         {
             Operation = OperationStatus.Running;
             try
             {
                 _connectionTester.Connect(connection);
                 IsBusy = true;
                 Operation = OperationStatus.Success;
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                 Operation = OperationStatus.Failure;
             }
             // Do something
             DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(
               () =>
               {
                   // Dispatch back to the main thread
                   IsBusy = false;
                   // without this the button stays disabled until a ui interaction occurs
                   System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
               });
         });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `Background` directly on the `Border`.  This is called a *local value*, and a local value takes precedence over a value set by any other source, including style/template triggers and setters.  Try removing `Background="{StaticResource Gradient3}"` from the `Border` declaration, add a `Setter` to your `Style` to set the default background:

```
<Border.Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Gradient3}" />
    ...
```

You'll need to do the same for any other values that you want to update with triggers, e.g., `BorderBrush`.